# how do I change 'username-password login' to 'email-password login' on django-registration

Tags: python, django

how do I change 'username-password login' to 'email-password login' on django-registration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't easily store emails in `django.contrib.auth.model.User`'s username field, so you'll need a different auth backend. Put the following somewhere and add its path to `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`. See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#writing-an-authentication-backend

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class EmailBackend(object):
    """ Authenticates against the email field of django.contrib.auth.models.User
    """

    def authenticate(self, email=None, password=None):
        # Try using the email if it is given
        if email:
            for user in User.objects.filter(email=email):
                if user.check_password(password):
                    return user

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Then, in your views, authenticate by calling `django.contrib.auth.authenticate`.

Two things to note:

- You will probably want to keep the default `AUTHENTICATION_BACKEND` there, especially if you want to use the Django admin.
- If users are signing themselves up without a username, you'll need to create one for them. I use the base64 version of a uuid for that

Set the username in a save method somewhere (eg in your new user form):

```
import uuid, binascii
username = binascii.b2a_base64(uuid.uuid4().bytes)
```

Comment: +1 for 'You can't easily store emails'. The User.username field a) is only 30 chars long and that's not long enough for some emails, and b) it requires the name to match '\w+', which does not allow things like '@' or '.'. This does create the problem of what to *use* for the username (since it's required) if you only want to focus on email addrs. I recommend slugifying the email (e.g. foo@bar.com => foo_bar_com), trim to 30 chars and storing that (but be prepared to handle accidental collisions). The user will never see it, and your authentication backend will completely ignore it.

Comment: in 1.2 you can use emails for login

Comment: more on that: 1.2 now allows chars that are in emails to be used in usernames (see http://code.djangoproject.com/changeset/12634). As the commit message admits, it's not a complete solution as the max length is still only 30 chars.